# what is diference between Security Domain with Delegated Management privilege and Authorized management?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I want to know difference between Security Domain with Authorized Management privilege and Security Domain with delegated Management privilege. And what we do operation in two state(like loading, installing,...). I read Global platform 2.2.1 about this subject, But I understand meaning and different yet, And I want know for which privilege I can make or create security domain? And how do I found my card which privilege supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security domain with AM privilege can perform all the Card Content Management operations without an authorization, However SD with a DM priviledge requires a Authorization of the Card Content MAnagement Operation from a SD with AM privilege via Token verification.

Please go through Table 6-3 of GP2.2.1 for Privilege Assignment Example Use Cases, the Privilege Assignment can change from requirement.

The Privilege can be retrived from Get Status command it will be returned by TAg 'C5'in Response Message.

Feel free in case further information is required